# Is it possible to implement server side sorting and pagging in dhtml grid?

Tags: ajax, dhtml

I want to implement DHTML grid . Which required server side sorting and pegging with ajax support.
Dose any one having any idea about how to implement this.

Comment: Are you talking about the dHTMLx grid http://dhtmlx.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement server side sorting then it does not matter what technology you are using in the front end.

On a conceptual level you can do the following things:

1. Write a SortingServlet which takes your grid and sorts it according to the request parameters passed to it and renders the output in the form of json(not strictly required but good to have)
2. Use jQuery to make a Ajax call to this servlet and then format the response when you get it back.